# How do I anchor my footer but keep my content height 100%

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I was working with [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), but it wasn't working out as it should and was giving something like 200 or 400 px of extension past the viewport.

I thought it would be easier to show what I need rather than explain it, see below:

[image]

EDIT: I updated my code to reflect what it looks like with sticky footer.

[Sticky Footer jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mBdy/)

**ORIGINAL**
And here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      Content
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Also noticed that I have a sidebar in the code but not in the picture provided. I will need a sidebar as well without a background.

Comment: How do you expect help solving a CSS issue, if you don't show your CSS?

Comment: Percentage height depends upon its parent, when the parent is `position: absolute`, otherwise it falls back to `height: auto`, which is exactly what you're seeing.  When you apply `absolute` to the parent, you totally break your layout.  I don't think it's possible without JavaScript but I could be wrong.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property.

Comment: What is the status of this question?  People have tried to help and yet no response at all from the OP since it was posted.

Comment: None of the answers provided met my needs/answered my question. I ended up choosing to use z-index to overlay the top and bottom over the body, sacrificing the 100% height of the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not follow the tutorial or I'd see an empty `div` with class `push` in your `wrapper`. Also, `footer` should not be inside your `wrapper`.

As per the [online tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)...

```
<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                Header
            </header>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="content">
                    Content
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    Sidebar
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </footer>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
   height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as footer */
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo Page](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ9Hj/show/)

Please try the above and post your actual CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to anchor the footer at the bottom.

```
.footer {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
height:30px;
}
```

Comment: See [the example](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) posted by the OP.  That's not what your answer provides.